# Acetylene and Methane biology questions

Tags: science-based, evolution, xenobiology, biochemistry

First time poster, please be gentle.

Long story short, my own alien worldbuilding/speculative biology project involves the idea that cyanobacteria and other oxygen producers never evolved and other bacteria took its place. Life on this planet has evolved to be both autotrophic and heterotrophic at the same time, with varying degrees one way or the other. To fill plant and animal type rolls.

I'm willing to change my world given new information but its planned to be a metal rich world with increased volcanism and similar temperatures to earth. The "increased volcanism" is an early idea to explain outgassing early microbes could exploit and how usually rare metals (Titanium, Platinum, Chromium, ect...) are commonly accessible. This is subject to change.

Is my proposed "Carbon" cycle theoretically sound? I'm not a chemistry major by any stretch.
I believe the reactions are balanced throughout the plant/animal cycle, where the Plants come to a net positive enthalpy and animals come to a net negative. Could liquid water even exist on this planet?

The main proposed atmospheric gases are and their quantities:

- Methane (4%)
- Acetylene (8%)
- Carbon Dioxide (10%)
- Hydrogen (Trace gas)
- Nitrogen (75%)

These atmospheric numbers don't come from any sources and are made up.

The "Plant" type roll:
*

- 3 CH4 + CO2 -> 2CH3CHO + 2H2
- C2H2 + H2O -> CH3CHO
- 2 CH3CHO + 5O2 -> 4CO2 + 4H2O
- 4CO2 + 2H2O -> 2C2H2 + 5O2*

Note that each of these are reactions that take place separately within the organism.
With Methane, Acetylene, and CO2 being broken down photosynthetically to provide energy in the form of Acetaldehyde. Releasing some Acetylene, CO2, and Hydrogen gas as waste.

The Animal type roll:
*

- CO2 + 4H2 -> CH4 + 2H2O
- C2H2 + 2O2 -> H2 + CO2
- CH3CHO + H2O -> C2H4O2 + H2
- C2H4O2 + H2O -> 2CH4 + 2O2*

These organisms would breath CO2, Acetylene, and Hydrogen. Looking to intake the Acetaldehyde to be broken down into Methane waste and usable oxygen. Again these reactions would take place separately.

The Oxygen's in these reactions are produced and used internally, mediated throughout the organism through some "magical enzyme" means. This idea comes from earth plants, in photosynthesis. A reaction that normally would take more energy that is gains, but its ok because SUN. The oxygen is not supposed to be energy balanced, but so there is no need or excess of the molecule.

If this idea is completely wrong please tell me. Or if you have better suggestions on what to use as an energy source I'd be happy to hear. Discussion on how life would potentially evolve using this system are welcome too.

Thanks to any and all who reply - Austin

Comment: Your species producing oxygen, what prevent it to accumulate in the atmosphere?

Comment: @RomainL. Sorry, I should have specified, the Oxygen is produced and used internally. That's why the Oxygen waste is the same amount needed to be used in another reaction.

Comment: Unless you as the worldbuilder simply "make it so" it's very hard for me to believe there won't be *any* free oxygen in the atmosphere - to combine with three highly combustible gases in large quantities. The only thing you're missing is gaseous gasoline and a match (and I doubt you need the gasoline!). But, if I remember my college chemistry correctly, it's not enough to be chemically balanced, you must also be chemically stable, which is why our atmosphere's major component (Nitrogen) is explosively non-reactive. (Someone correct me if I'm wrong!) How much of your atmosphere is CO2?

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact Good point. I was hoping for an atmosphere loosely 75% Nitrogen, 10%CO2, 8%C2H2, and 4%CH4, the other trace gases could include Oxygen. Or I could fiddle with the numbers if you believe its needed. These numbers dont come from anywhere, I just made them up.

Comment: Now we have a question that doesn't involve the entire planet burning to a crisp when a volcano erupts! As a rule, never trust that people with read through comments. Always [edit] your question with answers to questions posed in comments.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact Good idea. Post has been edited, thank you. I seem to have gotten myself in a pickle, including that volcano bit. I was kind of crossing my fingers at the idea maybe there would be too little oxidizers to really worry about that. haha....

Comment: Acetylene is pretty energetic with its triple bonded carbon. It could be used as storage, but, unlikely to be a waste product. Ethane C2H6  is much more likely. You need to consider whats more likely energy wise as well if you are going for hard science plausible.

Comment: as a biologist I have to tell you that oxygen is toxic, but as world building magic enzyme may cut it. We breathe oxygen because it is an excellent electron acceptor. Briefly, you create energy by oxidizing sugar. Also, they are oxygene independant organisms you may want (or not) to look them for inspiration.

Comment: @GaultDrakkor So what you're saying is I could use Acetylene as a Glucose analog? What do you mean by Ethane as a waste product is more likely?

Comment: @Austinman42 broadly speaking waste products have less energy then the inputs. the whole metabolize things to get energy to do stuff.  The triple carbon bond represents comparatively more energy then a singly bonded carbon.

Comment: Are all the plant reactions meant to be endothermic and all animal reactions exothermic?

Comment: @GaultDrakkor That makes sense. Thank you for answering questions. I may go back to the drawing board with this.

Comment: @Willk This is where I say uhhh...maybe? From my limited understanding is that not what happens on Earth? Endothermic reactions require energy which could be explained as "alien photosynthesis"? right?

Comment: Yes: alien photosynthesis.  Plants plow captured light energy to make a reaction go, capturing that energy in the molecules they make.  Then later they break down those molecules and liberate that energy for their own use.  The part where they break down the molecules they have made are pretty similar between plants (autotrophs) and animals (heterotrophs).  I would like to get into the weeds with these reactions but it seems like there are more than one to capture energy and more than one to liberate it.  Cameo appearance of oxygen is also sort of unnerving.

Comment: @Willk I'm happy to explain my thought process. But yes, the idea was multiple "smaller" reactions taking place separately to add up to something capable of supporting complex life. The cameo of oxygen was really just me knowing oxidizing things releases energy and that might be worth throwing in the mix.

Comment: oxygen build up works because it is literally the most common element on the surface of the planet, by a larger margin.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that stand out as potentially problematic with your proposed carbon cycle.

First, the overall efficiency of converting methane and acetylene into useful energy is very low. This is because a lot of the energy that is released when these molecules are burned is in the form of heat, rather than light (which can be used to drive photosynthesis). As a result, it is unlikely that any organisms could use this carbon cycle as their primary source of energy.

Second, the presence of methane and acetylene in the atmosphere would make it very difficult for liquid water to exist on the surface of your planet. These molecules are both highly reactive, and would quickly react with water to form other compounds (such as carbon dioxide and water vapor). This would make it very difficult for life to exist on the surface of your planet.

Finally, it is worth noting that your proposed carbon cycle does not actually recycle any carbon. The net effect of the reactions you have listed is that methane and acetylene are converted into carbon dioxide and water vapor. While this might be fine for a planet with no life, it would not be sustainable over the long term if there was life present.

Overall, it seems like your proposed carbon cycle would not be able to support life on your planet. I would suggest reconsidering the atmospheric composition and/or the energy sources that you are using.